# How to align by columns, not rows, in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been having a lot of trouble finding out how to align my site this way using a grid system and could not find any questions regarding this when I searched.

I essentially want my site to layout like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emw0a.jpg), but when using Bootstrap's grid system like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s3">
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="col s9">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

If any content in the second column extends past the first it shifts the whole page down. Any ideas? I don't want the second column heights to be restricted by the bounds set by the first column.

Comment: I don't think Bootstrap can do this. You may need to roll your own solution using floats etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap does not offer this functionality.  You could achieve this effect using `Masonry.js`.  Take a look at this jQuery plugin.  It should do the trick.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

It is very well documented and easy to implement.  Good luck!